# Seek one value in Array and return the second one

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an array like:

```
[
    ["Reichertshofen", "ssh -p 10001 speed@norhfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.23.14:3389 -f sleep 50"],
    ["Zentralbuero", "ssh -p 10001 speed@nozbfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.38.14:3389 -f sleep 50"]
]
```

I would like to seek for the first value like "Reichertshofen" and get in return the second string.

How do I do that?

Comment: Any reason this data isn't in a Dictionary?

Comment: I got it out of a json file and it ended up like that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a dictionary, so my inclination is to represent the data as one.

```
let array = [
    ["Reichertshofen", "ssh -p 10001 speed@norhfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.23.14:3389 -f sleep 50"],
    ["Zentralbuero", "ssh -p 10001 speed@nozbfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.38.14:3389 -f sleep 50"]
]
```

**Swift 4**

```
let sequence = array.flatMap
{   entry -> (String, String)? in
    guard entry.count == 2 else { return nil }
    return (entry[0], entry[1])
}
let dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: sequence)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let dictionary = array.reduce([String:String]())
{   (dict, entry) in
    guard entry.count == 2 else { return dict }
    var dict = dict
    dict[entry[0]] = entry[1]
    return dict
}
```

Form there it's simply:

```
if let result = dictionary["Reichertshofen"]
{
    print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to seek for the first value like "Reichertshofen" and get in return the second string.

What you have is an array of arrays. It'll be clearer if you add some line breaks:

```
[
  ["Reichertshofen", "ssh -p 10001 speed@norhfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.23.14:3389 -f sleep 50"],
  ["Zentralbuero", "ssh -p 10001 speed@nozbfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.38.14:3389 -f sleep 50"]
]
```

So what you're asking for is the second element of the first subarray. In other words, if you have:

```
let people : [[String]] = [["Reichertshofen", "ssh -p 10001 speed@norhfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.23.14:3389 -f sleep 50"], ["Zentralbuero", "ssh -p 10001 speed@nozbfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.38.14:3389 -f sleep 50"]]
```

then the element you want is:

```
let element = people[0][1]
```

Keep in mind that arrays are indexed from zero, so the first element in an array is at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all arrays contain (at least) 2 items and you want to search always for the first item use

```
let data = [
    ["Reichertshofen", "ssh -p 10001 speed@norhfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.23.14:3389 -f sleep 50"],
    ["Zentralbuero", "ssh -p 10001 speed@nozbfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.38.14:3389 -f sleep 50"]
]

let search = "Reichertshofen"
if let found = data.first(where: {$0[0] == search }) {
    let script = found[1]
    print(script)
}
```

---

However I highly recommended to use a simple custom struct rather than a nested array. Names are more descriptive than indices.

```
struct Connection {
    let name, script : String
}

let data = [
    Connection(name: "Reichertshofen", script: "ssh -p 10001 speed@norhfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.23.14:3389 -f sleep 50"),
    Connection(name: "Zentralbuero", script: "ssh -p 10001 speed@nozbfa.anywareip.net -L 13389:192.168.38.14:3389 -f sleep 50")
]

let search = "Reichertshofen"
if let found = data.first(where: {$0.name == search }) {
    let script = found.script
    print(script)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// 1
for array in arrays {
    // 2
    if let index = array.index(of: "abc"),
        // 3
        (index + 1) < array.count {

        // 4
        return array[index + 1]
    }
}
```

1. Enumerate through array of arrays
2. Find index of required element
3. Check if there is next element after that index
4. Return desired value

Comment: Why do all that work? Arrays give you immediate access to any element -- you don't have to iterate through the whole thing.

Comment: "seek" means you need to find element. Array in question is just example and probably is dynamic. My solution works for any order or size of array.

Comment: var lstServers = [[String]]() is the variable I stored my data in. but I don't get where I get "arrays" from....

Comment: In my example "arrays" are equivalent your lstServers which is array of arrays.